# remove trailling zeros in string

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I would like to remove 0 after decimal in string field:

Start:

| size |
| --- |
| 60.0 ML |
| 45.50 S |
| 450.00 LL |

Expected result:

| size |
| --- |
| 60 ML |
| 45.5 S |
| 450 LL |

i used this for the moment:

```
TRIM(CONCAT(CAST(Regexp_extract(size,r'^(?:[^\s]*\s){0}([^\s]*)\s?') AS DECIMAL),'',Regexp_extract(size,r'^(?:[^\s]*\s){1}([^\s]*)\s?'))) as size
```

Is there an easier way to do it?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 2):

Consider this:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(str, r'\.?0*\s', ' ') 
  FROM UNNEST(['60.0 ML', '45.50 S', '450.00 LL']) str
```

[image]